# You have an error in your SQL syntax: ALTER Table

Tags: php, mysql, syntax

Can anyone help me find the syntax error in this code?

```
    $sql = "ALTER TABLE self_downloads DROP id; ALTER TABLE self_downloads AUTO_INCREMENT = 1; ALTER TABLE self_downloads ADD id int UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY FIRST;";
```

Thank you very,
John

Comment: As your converting all queries into a single string there must be termination of each query with `;`. Your missing `;` at the end of each query.

Comment: $sql = "ALTER TABLE `self_downloads` DROP `id`;";
    $sql.= "ALTER TABLE `self_downloads` AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;";
    $sql.= "ALTER TABLE `self_downloads` ADD `id` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY FIRST;";

Comment: That code returns this error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ALTER TABLE self_downloads AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;ALTER TABLE self_downloads ADD id ' at line 1.